# How do I run "Hello, world!" with WebSphere and Wicket?

Tags: java, websphere, wicket, websphere-7

I am a Wicket beginner, and I need to develop a Wicket application using WebSphere Application Server 7.0. I've searched Stack Overflow and Google, and found these resources

- http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-and-Websphere-td1917050.html#a1917051
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Websphere

but I can't figure out how to run a "Hello, world!" app on WebSphere. Can anyone tell me how to run one, step by step, using Wicket?

For example, for the step "Add a new property called `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility`," where will I add the property?

Answer (score 1):

I have Wicket 1.4 in production on WAS 7.0 and it works just fine - with one exception. I had to use the WicketServlet instead of the WicketFilter.

Try the following:

1. Create a [Wicket Quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) project
2. Modify the `web.xml` to use the Servlet instead of the Filter. The second link you provided contains instructions on how to do do.
3. Deploy!

I don't recall having to do anything special beyond that.

Note: As I use the Servlet, I have no need to use the `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility` property.